# Office password protection crack

Tags: passwords, protection, office

would just like to have a check on the password protection/encryption of MS office 2007 and above. It is said that its not that easy to crack the password protection except by brute force, since 2007 and above version of office use AES128bit encryption. Is this true till now, as in have you come across any cracking tools that is able to crack 2007 and above password protections?
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Elcomsoft Advanced Office Password Recovery](http://www.elcomsoft.com/aopr.html) may be what you're looking for; you'll need at least the Standard edition for GPU acceleration, and the Professional edition if you have more than one GPU or you want certain other features.

[John the Ripper Community-Enhanced (Jumbo)](http://www.openwall.com/john/) also has this capability.

Note that brute force is a poor cracking method once passwords reach reasonable lengths; mask attacks and rules-based dictionary attacks are much more efficient at many passwords humans choose.